# Kafka delivering duplicate message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

We are using kafka(0.9.0.0) for orchestrating command messages between different micro services.  We are finding an intermittent issue where duplicate messages are getting delivered to a particular topic.  The logs that occur when this issue happens is given below.  Can some one help to understand this issue

```
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - WARNING Coordinator unknown during heartbeat -- will retry
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - WARNING Heartbeat failed; retrying
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - WARNING <BrokerConnection host=AZSG-D-BOT-DEV4 port=9092> timed out after 40000 ms. Closing connection.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - ERROR Fetch to node 1 failed: RequestTimedOutError - 7 - This error is thrown if the request exceeds the user-specified time limit in the request.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - INFO Marking the coordinator dead (node 1): None.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - INFO Group coordinator for kafka-python-default-group is BrokerMetadata(nodeId=1, host=u'AZSG-D-BOT-DEV4', port=9092)
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - ERROR OffsetCommit failed for group kafka-python-default-group due to group error (UnknownMemberIdError - 25 - Returned from group requests (offset commits/fetches, heartbeats, etc) when the memberId is not in the current generation.), will rejoin
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - WARNING Offset commit failed: group membership out of date This is likely to cause duplicate message delivery.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - ERROR LeaveGroup request failed: UnknownMemberIdError - 25 - Returned from group requests (offset commits/fetches, heartbeats, etc) when the memberId is not in the current generation.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - INFO Marking the coordinator dead (node 1): None.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - INFO Group coordinator for kafka-python-default-group is BrokerMetadata(nodeId=1, host=u'AZSG-D-BOT-DEV4', port=9092)
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - ERROR OffsetCommit failed for group kafka-python-default-group due to group error (UnknownMemberIdError - 25 - Returned from group requests (offset commits/fetches, heartbeats, etc) when the memberId is not in the current generation.), will rejoin
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:07 - WARNING Offset commit failed: group membership out of date This is likely to cause duplicate message delivery.
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:10 - INFO Joined group 'kafka-python-default-group' (generation 5) with member_id kafka-python-1.0.2-8585f310-cb4f-493a-a98d-12ec9810419b
Wed, 21-Sep-2016 09:19:10 - INFO Updated partition assignment: [TopicPartition(topic=u'ilinaTestPlatformReq', partition=0)]
```

Comment: That may happen if a consumer is blocked processing a message for longer than the `session.timeout`. How much time does it roughly take for the consumer to process a message?

Comment: Yes.  That is right. Roughly the failure occurs when ever the consumer takes more than 30 seconds. Other wise things are fine.  So is increasing the session.timeout the right fix ?

Comment: By the way please provide your kafka-python version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Kafka documentation on Consumer config](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs):

> `session.timeout.ms` (default 30000) - the timeout used to detect
>   failures when using Kafka's group management facilities. When a
>   consumer's heartbeat is not received within the session timeout, the
>   broker will mark the consumer as failed and rebalance the group. Since
>   heartbeats are sent only when `poll()` is invoked, a higher session
>   timeout allows more time for message processing in the consumer's poll
>   loop at the cost of a longer time to detect hard failures. See also
>   `max.poll.records` for another option to control the processing time in
>   the poll loop. Note that the value must be in the allowable range as
>   configured in the broker configuration by `group.min.session.timeout.ms`
>   and `group.max.session.timeout.ms`.

Seems that if the message processing time is greater than 30000 ms, consumer rebalancing is triggered which may cause duplicate message delivery.

What you can try is to increase `session.timeout.ms`.

Another option is to process messages asynchronously while using [pause()](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/kafka.consumer.html#kafka.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pause) before processing a message and [resume()](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/kafka.consumer.html#kafka.consumer.KafkaConsumer.resume) after a message processed. In this case the consumer will call `poll()` (and send heartbeats) even if processing time takes longer than `session.timeout.ms`. Thus broker won't mark your consumer as failed and no rebalancing will be initiated.

Comment: Thank you Aliaxander.  The problem was solved by increasing the following values  
    group.min.session.timeout.ms=xxx
    session.timeout.ms=xxx
    group.max.session.timeout.ms=xxx